# My function parameters is not working as expected

Tags: javascript, function, parameters, parameter-passing

Sorry for the stupid question.
So I got this code here:

```
function stat(x) {
    player.ATK = 0; player.DEF = 0; player.DEX = 0; player.crit = 0; player.HP = 0;
    player.weaponATK = weapon.x.atk;
    player.weaponDEF= weapon.x.def;
    player.weaponDEX = weapon.x.dex;
    player.weaponHP = weapon.x.hp;
    player.weaponCrit = weapon.x.crit;
    player.ATK = player.baseATK + player.weaponATK;
    player.DEF = player.baseDEF + player.weaponDEF;
    player.DEX = player.baseDEX + player.weaponDEX;
    player.HP = player.baseHP + player.weaponHP;
    player.crit = player.baseCrit + player.weaponCrit;
}
```

And here's the whole var i use:

```
var player = {
  HP: 0,
  baseHP: 100,
  weaponHP: 0,
  ATK: 0,
  baseATK: 0,
  weaponATK: 0,
  DEF: 0,
  baseDEF: 0,
  weaponDEF: 0,
  DEX: 0,
  baseDEX: 0,
  weaponDEX: 0,
  crit: 0,
  baseCrit: 5,
  weaponCrit: 0,
  level: 1,
  currentEXP: 0,
  expLeft: 10
};
var weapon = {
  hatchet: {
    atk: 2,
    def: -1,
    dex: 0,
    hp: 0,
    crit: 0
  },
  woodenSword: {
    atk: 5,
    dex: 0,
    def: 0,
    hp: 0,
    crit: 0,
  },
  ironSword: {
    atk: 10,
    crit: 5,
    dex: 0,
    def: 0,
    hp: 0
  },
  blade: {
    atk: 25,
    crit: 20,
    dex: 10,
    hp: 0,
    crit: 0,
  },
  mace: {
    atk: 30,
    def: 5,
    dex: -1,
    hp: 0,
    crit: 0,
  },
  battleAxe: {
    atk: 50,
    def: 5,
    dex: 0,
    hp: 0,
    crit: 0,
  },
  broadSword: {
    atk: 100,
    def: 20,
    dex: 0,
    crit: 0,
    hp: 0
  },
  woodenShield: {
    atk: 0,
    def: 10,
    dex: 0,
    hp: 0,
    crit: 0,
  },
  spikeShield: {
    def: 15,
    atk: 5,
    dex: 0,
    crit: 0,
    hp: 0,
  },
  bomb: {
    atk: 0,
    def: 0,
    crit: 0,
    hp: 0,
    dex: -5
  }
};
```

And if I run `stat(hatchet)`, it suppose to excute the function with `x` replace with `hatchet`. But instead, I got a error: "x is not defined". Can someone help me?
Thanks for the help.

Comment: what is `hatchet` defined as?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Dynamically access object property using variable](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4244896/dynamically-access-object-property-using-variable)

Comment: the parameter is `x` but you are trying to access `weapon.x`

Comment: @PatrickRoberts hatchet is define as a variable

Comment: Just simply send `weapon.x` as parameter. Check if it works.

Comment: @GSURENDARTHINA Now i got "Unexpected Token ."

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I assume that x is a property in weapon object, so you can use the bracket notation to access it from weapon like the following. Finally, when you call stat function, make sure that it is a string. See working code below:

```js
var player = {
  HP: 0,
  baseHP: 100,
  weaponHP: 0,
  ATK: 0,
  baseATK: 0,
  weaponATK: 0,
  DEF: 0,
  baseDEF: 0,
  weaponDEF: 0,
  DEX: 0,
  baseDEX: 0,
  weaponDEX: 0,
  crit: 0,
  baseCrit: 5,
  weaponCrit: 0,
  level: 1,
  currentEXP: 0,
  expLeft: 10
};
var weapon = {
  hatchet: {
    atk: 2,
    def: -1,
    dex: 0,
    hp: 0,
    crit: 0
  },
  woodenSword: {
    atk: 5,
    dex: 0,
    def: 0,
    hp: 0,
    crit: 0,
  },
  ironSword: {
    atk: 10,
    crit: 5,
    dex: 0,
    def: 0,
    hp: 0
  },
  blade: {
    atk: 25,
    crit: 20,
    dex: 10,
    hp: 0,
    crit: 0,
  },
  mace: {
    atk: 30,
    def: 5,
    dex: -1,
    hp: 0,
    crit: 0,
  },
  battleAxe: {
    atk: 50,
    def: 5,
    dex: 0,
    hp: 0,
    crit: 0,
  },
  broadSword: {
    atk: 100,
    def: 20,
    dex: 0,
    crit: 0,
    hp: 0
  },
  woodenShield: {
    atk: 0,
    def: 10,
    dex: 0,
    hp: 0,
    crit: 0,
  },
  spikeShield: {
    def: 15,
    atk: 5,
    dex: 0,
    crit: 0,
    hp: 0,
  },
  bomb: {
    atk: 0,
    def: 0,
    crit: 0,
    hp: 0,
    dex: -5
  }
};

function stat(x) {
    player.ATK = 0; player.DEF = 0; player.DEX = 0; player.crit = 0; player.HP = 0;
    player.weaponATK = weapon[x].atk;
    player.weaponDEF= weapon[x].def;
    player.weaponDEX = weapon[x].dex;
    player.weaponHP = weapon[x].hp;
    player.weaponCrit = weapon[x].crit;
    player.ATK = player.baseATK + player.weaponATK;
    player.DEF = player.baseDEF + player.weaponDEF;
    player.DEX = player.baseDEX + player.weaponDEX;
    player.HP = player.baseHP + player.weaponHP;
    player.crit = player.baseCrit + player.weaponCrit;
}

// make sure x is a string!
stat('hatchet');

console.log(player)
```

Comment: will dot notation still work? Or bracket notaion is a must?

Comment: In this case, only bracket notation would work. Dot notation would only work if you are assigning a value to a known property in the object. For example, you want to update the player.baseHP, so you can do `player.baseHP = someVariable`.

Comment: I try your code, and it says "Cannot  read property atk of undefine.

Comment: The code snippet above works, just try running the code snippet. That error means that weapon object is not defined in your case.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/145756/discussion-between-azdeveloper-and-d-reaper).

Answer (score 0):

It's either what @brk or @D-reaper suggested

```
player.weaponATK = weapon.x.atk;
```

and similar need to be either

```
player.weaponATK = weapon[x].atk;
```

or just

```
player.weaponATK = x.atk;
```

Answer (score 0):

Since x is key passed to access the object property. It has to be used as
 **`weapon[x].atk`**